# Need to control (fade in/out, not just turn it on and off) a 240 V heat lamp. Is this even possible?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, high-voltage

I'm a MechE and i'm way over my head in a project i'm working on. i need to be able to send either an analog or PWM signal to a heat lamp to allow it to fade in and out from dSPACE via a Unity project. is it even possible? I looked into MOSFETs and solid state relays and neither of them seemed to be satisfactory. any help would be awesome.

Comment: Could you address some of the design considerations for this project? What's the power consumption of the lamp / current requirements. Is the current / heat output a linear relationship or is it nonlinear? A PWM driver circuit can certainly be built with a ramp controlled PWM signal if that's what you want, but so far it's unclear

Comment: The magic circuit is a "triac dimmer", but for prebuilt solutions you might want to consider digital theatre lighting equipment.

Comment: You also state 240V (supply?) - is that AC or DC? It makes a huge difference to a suitable answer.

Comment: Oh sorry its 240V AC. the power of the lamp is 1600W at max so about 7A of current.

Comment: What does "dSPACE via a Unity project" mean?

Comment: What is the fade in/out duration?

Comment: dSPACE is basically computer software that functions like a giant arduino that is getting command protocols from a Unity game engine environment. And the fade in out time is not set, i need to be able to precisely control the temperature of the lamp, which a colleague had done some tests on to determine a mathematical relationship between voltage and filament temperature.

Answer (score 2):

The power part of the solution is quite simple using a linear proportional controller. For example, this type of controller uses an analog 0-5V or 0-10V signal to control the switch-on time of a triac which feeds your load.

[image]

*Figure 1. Linear proportional controller wiring.*

The output of this will generate a variable AC power with waveform as shown in Figure 2.

[image]

*Figure 2. Proportional control of AC power.*

Link: [Linear proportional controller](http://www.crydom.com/en/products/catalog/l_pcv.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

That is the same as dimming an incandescent lamp. There are a lot of solutions depending on whether you want to build something from scratch or buy a dimmer module.

Comment: It seems like he needs to build some sort of automatic control module, maybe give links to some generic module that might work for his application?

Comment: The only dimmer modules I could find were mechanical and i have to be able to control it using a 0-10 VDC signal.

Comment: If you have some purchased hardware that is generating the 0-10 VDC signal, look for accessories for that called drivers or control amplifiers or even light dimmer modules. Or just search for "analog input light dimmer."

Comment: @Captainj2001 We don't find products for people here. We try to explain what is needed or give design assistance.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I agree, we do not find products, however the answer you provided isn't really an answer to the question either. Saying "there are solutions" but keeping them out of your answer doesn't do much.